# How to Customize a "complex" mapping between model and database table in Entity Framework Code First

Tags: entity-framework

Is it possible to add a custom attribute(Data Annotation), named "IP" for example:

```
public class User
{
   public int UserId {get; set;}

   [IP]
   public string UserIP {get; set;}
}
```

In this case, [IP] include [MaxLengt(20)] and [Column("IP")], or more other data annotation.

```
public class User
{
   public int UserId {get; set;}

   [MaxLength(20)]
   [Column("IP")]
   public string UserIP {get; set;}
}
```

I also need the [IP] data annotation can work in code first automatic migration.

Any help will be appreciated. Thank you!